# How to grant View builds permissions to be able to view tags for a project

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to [get tags for a team project in Azure DevOps using REST Client provided by VSTS/TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/client/api/tfs/build/restclient/buildhttpclient2_1?view=azure-devops#gettags()), but I keep getting an exception.

My code looks like this (simplified):

```
List<string> tags = new List<string>();

using (var client = new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildHttpClient(uri, credentials))
{
   tags = await client.GetTagsAsync("<project>");
}
```

But I get this Access Denied Exception:

> An exception of type
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.AccessDeniedException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: TF215002: Access denied. [Account] needs View builds
>   permissions for team project [Project] to perform the action. For more
>   information, contact the Azure DevOps administrator.

I've tried to google and also look through various Microsoft documentation online but couldn't find anything...

Also, I've tried to look through all Security Permissions for my team project in Azure DevOps but couldn't find this "View builds permissions" anywhere.

How and where to grant the "View builds permissions" to my account?

My account needs only permissions to view/get the tags for my team project and does not need to either create, update or delete the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the builds page, there is `Security` in the `...` link next to `Queue`, and it has `View builds` permission.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer - unfortunately does my user account not have proper rights to grant that permission, so I need to contact my Azure DevOps Administrator, but at least now I know, where to find this permission.

Thanks again for your answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

A mentioned above, this feature is available with Azure DevOps. We can provide any level of granular permissions to the users.

For the actual real-life implementation, I would suggest you create an "Azure DevOps Groups" of users in the permissions Tab from the security menu.

This will help you group the users of a particular real-life group like the Developers, Testers, Managers, Product Owners together. Then instead of providing them with individual permissions, you can do for the complete group at the same time.

Since you mentioned that you are working for a larger group of Audience. This feature would be really helpful for you!